# Querying a foreign key on a association table

Tags: mysql, associations

Let's say i have the following model:

```
Customer(customer_id (PK), firstName, lastName, email)
Item(item_id (PK), name, description)
Orders(orders_id (PK), customer_id (FK), item_id (FK), promotion_id (FK)),
Promotion(promotion_id (PK), date, gift_id (FK))
Gift(gift_id (PK), name, description)
```

Now, let's say that i have the following requirement:

> Retrieve the list of all orders (not grouped by) from all customers and the name column from both the item and gift associated.

The difficult part is that the association table orders has a foreign key column to a one to many table (promotion) that, in his turn, has the foreign key to the gift;
I have the following query that worked, but i figure out that should have a more elegant way to approach the problem than doing a lot of joins like this:

```
select concat(c.firstName, ' ', c.lastName) as customerName,
       i.name, g.name
from   customer as c
left join orders as o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
inner join item as i on o.item_id = i.item_id
inner join promotion as p on o.promotion_id = p.promotion_id
inner join gift as g on p.gift_id = g.gift_id;
```

How i could resolve the query in a more elegant way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is perfectly elegant. Joins are very classy and often misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the `INNER` keywords as joins are inner by default, and the `AS` keywords are optional; also because your column names are the same across the joins, you can simply use `USING` instead of `ON`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', c.firstName, c.lastName) customerName,
       i.name, g.name
FROM   customer    c
  LEFT JOIN orders o USING (customer_id)
  JOIN item        i USING (item_id)
  JOIN promotion   p USING (promotion_id)
  JOIN gift        g USING (gift_id)
```

Indeed, if those are the only columns having the same name across the joined tables one could go further and use `NATURAL` joins (although I don't like that as it hides what's going on if the schema changes):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', c.firstName, c.lastName) customerName,
       i.name, g.name
FROM   customer            c
  NATURAL LEFT JOIN orders o
  NATURAL JOIN item        i
  NATURAL JOIN promotion   p
  NATURAL JOIN gift        g
```

Comment: I prefer to specify INNER JOIN rather than just JOIN, just to confirm that's what you really wanted.